# Playing local file from www folder

Tags: cordova

I'm attempting to use the Media functions of PhoneGap 2.7.0 to play a file that's locally stored inside the www folder. No matter what I do or how I reference the file, I can't make it work.

(The app is for iOs)

Error:
"Cannot use audio file from resource xxxx", error code 1

I've tried giving the path like this:

```
"media/rock.mp3"
"www/media/rock.mp3"
"file://var/mobile/Applications/..../www/media/rock.mp3"
"/var/mobile/Applications/..../www/media/rock.mp3"
```

They all produce the same error. Playing a file remotely with a http address however works perfectly.

Here's my code:

```
function spillLyd_lokal() {
var sti = window.location.pathname;
sti = "file:/" + sti.replace('index.html', '');
var url = sti + "media/rock.mp3";
var my_media = new Media(url,
    function () {
        alert("playAudio():Audio Success");
    },
    function (err) {
        alert("playAudio():Audio Error: " + JSON.stringify(err));
    }
);
my_media.play();
```

}

Comment: Hey have you had any luck?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I already tried file:// with no success.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what to suggest then.  Sorry I suggested something you already tried.  It might be an actual issue on the native side in PhoneGap 2.7.0 - Are you able to successfully play different media files?

Comment: Playing remote files works fine, it's only the local ones I'm struggling with. Perhaps PhoneGap doesn't expect the files to be in the www directory at all, I'll give it a try putting them outside.

Comment: My cordova log file reports files from the Camera working in the Webview with the path file:///var/mobile/Applications/... this has changed in XCode5/iOS7 and is 2 characters longer than before. I suspect file:///var instead file:/var

Comment: Did you ever get this working, I'm experiencing the same issue.

Comment: Sorry, I never managed to solve this, and ended up just streaming the file from the server. If you find a solution, please share it here.